# Animate changes in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

Can anyone tell me how I can swap individual slivers in a CustomScrollView animated?

The only possibility I know of is to swap the complete CustomScrollView. The problem here is that my SliverAppBar is also swapped.

Is there no possibility here?